# getClientOriginalName() on null

Tags: laravel

I have a little problem with one request file in my Store controller !

I get the orginal file name extension like this :

```
$licencie_amateur->cert_medical_surclassement = $request->file('cert_medical_surclassement')->getClientOriginalName();
```

Sometimes the user don't need to put a file "cert_medical_surclassement" i would like to do a condition like : If the file was added ok but if there is no files in the field i pass to the other variable .

Someone know how i could do this ? thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`hasFile()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_hasFile) method

```
if ($request->hasFile('cert_medical_surclassement')) {
    $licencie_amateur->cert_medical_surclassement = $request->file('cert_medical_surclassement')->getClientOriginalName();
} else {
    // else code
}
```

More info: [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files)